# MFC Custom Control Background/Text Color

Tags: c++, mfc

So I have used MFC for a few years and made various interfaces which include custom controls. I was recently asked to start making an interface which can have dynamically set background and text colors. I started working on this and have been running into an issue getting some of my custom controls to behave. All the controls which generate WM_CTLCOLOR messages work really nicely using that interface to allow the parent to set the colors of the child controls, but not all the controls I have customized generate these messages. Specifically a class I built off of CTabCrtl and a few based on CWnd. These classes don't seem to generate WM_CTLCOLOR messages before they call a paint.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to either get the background and text color of a controls parent CWnd or how to manually create a WM_CTLCOLOR message. I have tried to get the current DC of the controls parent so I can call GetBkColor() and GetTextColor() but doing this always seems to return default values. I have also tried to create WM_CTLCOLOR messages but don't know where I should create them or the exact syntax.. Any help would be great.

Comment: Many common controls support customisation via `WM_NOTIFY/NM_CUSTOMDRAW`

Comment: Depending on which controls you're targeting, you might find that the MFC Feature Pack that emerged from VS2008 SP1 has some useful additions. For example [CMFCListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983191.aspx) has overrides for setting foreground/background cell colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of WM_CTLCOLOR is that is has to be called from within the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND. 
In such cases you have a DC. You send the message to the parent and you get a brush and the text and  background Color gets set.

I see only a major problem that WM_CTLCOLOR isn't a real window message... it is just syntesized from the various WM_CTLCOLOR... messages described in the SDK.

So the syntax is documented in the MSDN.
Cast the DC handle to WPARAM and hast the window handle to LPARAM...

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I always use PostMessage() when sending messages and forgot how SendMessage() worked. I couldn't figure out how I could get the WM_CTLCOLOR processed before the WM_PAINT when it was being called from the paint routine.  

`HDC hdc = ::GetDC(this->m_hWnd);  
HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH) ::SendMessage(GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, (WPARAM)hdc, (LPARAM)this);  
CDC *dc = CDC::FromHandle(hdc);`

The exact WM_CTLCOLOR message can be changed depending on how you want your color assignment handled  

Thanks!